# ¿Cómo lograr que los componentes hijos tengan el mismo tamaño que el padre al modificarlos por código en WPF?

Tags: windows-forms, wpf, menú, usercontrol

Programo en WinForms desde hace tiempo por que es lo que me vienen enseñando en la universidad, y hace unos dias investigando descubri WPF, es magia!
Estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto directamente en WPF, por el momento me arreglo con varias cosas, cambia un poco, pero va bien.

No estoy entendiendo otras, por ejemplo como funcionan los hijos?

Estoy copiando la interfaz de un programa que realize a WPF, y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

[image: Menu]

En WinForms ( lado izquierdo ), puedo realizar ese menu simplemente con panels, dentro de un panel grande inserto paneles mas pequeños que contienen la imagen y el label.

[image: Esquema WinForm]

Cuando presiono los 3 puntos, el Contenedor cambia su ancho (se expande o contrae). muy facil nada de complicacion

Pero en WPF me encuentro con lo siguiente, hice exactamente lo mismo que mencione arriba pero en ves de Panel uso Canvas, al cambiar el ancho los controles sobrepasan al padre y se ven por encima.

[image: Esquema WPF]

Como soluciono esto?

Comment: Hola @Andy, puede que te interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [ask], trata de mostrar lo que llevas para que te puedan ayudar . Saludos.

Comment: No uses canvas.. no.. nunca... usa los paneles, funcionan igual que en winforms...

Comment: @gbianchi para usar los paneles, tengo que importar alguna libreria o algo?

Comment: No. tenes montones de controles para hacer eso.. inclusive maquetear todo como una gran grilla.. pero no uses canvas.. vienen incluidos en wpf...

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa la demora en responder, Me serivio tu comentario, escribilo como respuesta que la marco como correcta ;D

Comment: No sabria que poner en una respuesta, pero que bueno que mi comentario te sirvio. Si no podes poner vos una respuesta, elimina la pregunta.